# Why are my logs full of H13 /graphql/websocket?vsn=2.0.0?

Tags: heroku, slash-graphql

I'm not using GraphQL. I'm guessing these are some sort of robot crawler looking for vulnerabilities?

```
2023-09-21T10:07:10.003257+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/graphql/websocket?vsn=2.0.0" host=intend.do request_id=3748f067-774f-4f33-b45c-8637504e9f73 fwd="132.64.189.89" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

They're not ordinary requests, because when I just do an ordinary GET request to that url, it loads fine (I mean it loads a 404 page but it doesn't have an H13 issue).

When I tried to set up custom logs for that url to find out what was going on, I discover that these mysterious requests don't actually reach my application code as far as I can tell.

Are they websocket requests and that's why they're getting H13s? It says https not wss, but idk. Is there any way to just block them? I need to not have platform errors showing up for something that isn't actually a problem in any way and that there's nothing I can do about.